# Why is public method in private struct accessible

Tags: c++, private

Why does this code compile and `lib::Foo::SecretStruct::SecretFunc` can be accessed despite `SecretStruct` being `private`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

namespace lib {
template <typename T> struct Bar {};

struct Foo {
private:
  struct SecretStruct {
    static void SecretFunc() {
      std::cout << "super secret function is called\n";
    }
  };

public:
  using TBar = Bar<SecretStruct>;
};
} // namespace lib

template <typename T> struct GetSecretImpl {};
template <typename T>
struct GetSecretImpl<lib::Bar<T>> : std::type_identity<T> {};

int main() {
  using SecretT = typename GetSecretImpl<lib::Foo::TBar>::type;
  SecretT::SecretFunc();
}
```

Comment: `private` access is good at preventing accidental access. It's not so good at preventing deliberate access.

Comment: There is no principle difference here with declaring a private nested struct then have a public function return it: if the private type becomes part of a public interface, there is no way you can prevent it from being used.

Comment: `std::type_identity` -- You should tag this as C++20.  This code will fail to compile with C++17 or earlier.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Move `using TBar = Bar<SecretStruct>;`  to the `private`  section if you don't want people to have access to it.

Comment: Looks like a design fault to me in first place. If a struct is part of the public interface it should reside in the public section as well. You still could make the *members* of the nested class private and the surrounding one a friend of, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EE9fz6zje).

Comment: If you were pedantic you could even go further restricting access of data of the nested class to the surrounding one as well by going yet another nesting level deeper ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/adWcd1nb5)) ;) A nested class, however, in the end is an implementation detail and the surrounding one should know itself what to do with which data and which one not to touch (usually at least; maybe in some complex scenarios this indeed might prevent errors?).

Comment: If you have a type based on a template, you could pick the template parameter type via index if you'd like. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/GYzcsTeze)

Comment: With `using TBar = Bar<SecretStruct>;` you have explicitly placed `SecretStruct`  in the public interface of `Foo`, and then via `using SecretT = typename GetSecretImpl<lib::Foo::TBar>::type` in `main()` specified a type alias that references it.    `private` is not some absolute prohibition on access.   If your class cooperates (by defining something in its own `public` interface in terms of something that is `private`), then it effectively grants (via an indirect means) `public` access.   Change so the `using TBar = Bar<SecretStruct>` is `private`, and `SecretStruct` will not be accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything private that becomes a part of a public interface becomes visible to code outside.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Outer
{
private:
    struct Inner { static void Foo() { std::cout << "Foo.\n"; } };

public:
    static Inner GetInner();
};

int main()
{
    decltype(Outer::GetInner()) inner;
    inner.Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Since `Inner` is the return type of a public member function, it can be used by code outside `Outer` despite itself being a private struct.

Your code is more involved but in principle does the same thing:

```cpp
public:
  using TBar = Bar<SecretStruct>;
```

`TBar` is part of the public interface. `SecretStruct` is used by `TBar`, so it also becomes a part of the public interface.

---

In C++, the access modifiers only control access to names. This means you cannot use the names `Outer::Inner` (in my example) or `lib::Foo::SecretStruct` directly from outside the scope they are declared in. In those cases, name lookup is performed first to identify the entity being accessed, then the found entity is checked with access rules.

If there are others ways to access an entity indirectly without spelling out its partial or fully qualified name, access modifiers can't stop them.